# How Can I Install pytorch on Intel & python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytorch, intel-python

I often saw how to install pytorch on intel & python3
but no python2...!

How can I install pytorch on intel & python2

Comment: Python2 is end of life in a month. Just use Python3

Comment: In general, though, you install packages the exact same way in Python2 and 3, so what happens when you try?

Comment: What OS?  Most people run operating systems on their computers, like Linux or Windows, not Python right on the bare metal (e.g. from a UEFI bootloader), and software installation depends as much on the OS as on x86-64 vs. ARM vs. PowerPC or whatever.  I assume you mean "x86" when you say "Intel"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install PyTorch in two ways

Using `pip` and
Using `conda`

PyTorch installation using pip

```
pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

PyTorch installation via `conda`

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```